# What's the proper way to use RTK Query when dealing with multiple base URLS?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have migrated towards RTK and enjoying it immensely so far, but one thing I got stuck on is the following situation:

We have (for keeping it simple's sake) two endpoints:

- [www.domain-customer.com](http://www.domain-customer.com) <- fetching customer data
- [www.domain-order.com](http://www.domain-order.com) <- can mutate some user data here

And the website itself is hosted on another domain.

I need to fetch data from the customer endpoint, but in order to update certain things I need to make a mutation to the order endpoint. At first I thought I should define a createApi per base URL, but then I'm pretty sure I can't have the invalidation. I would like to have this previous mutation invalidate the data for the customer, so that the new data gets refetched.

So this is what I have come up with, but I'd like some input on if this is the way to move forward.

```
export const customerApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "/../",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://www.domain-customer.com/" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
// write provides tag stuff here
    getCustomerExample: builder.query({ query: (name) => `customer/${name}` }),
// please ignore the details of the mutation, I haven't practiced much with it yet.
    updateCustomer: builder.mutation({
      queryFn: async (name) => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://www.domain-order.com/updateCustomer`,
           {update mutation stuff here}
        );
        const data = await response.json();

        return { data };
      }
// write invalidate stuff here
    })
  })
});
```

Is this the way to go about it? Or should there even be a giant createAPI that will hold all the mutations and queries?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, yes, you should have one single `createApi` if data is connected enough that you want to invalidate them.

Note that while most examples just show queries to something under `baseQuery`, you can also just have a `url` parameter (or string) returned from `query` that contains a full domain -`fetchBaseQuery` 100% supports that use case.

So in your case:

```js
updateCustomer: builder.mutation({
      query: (name) => ({
        url: `https://www.domain-order.com/updateCustomer`,
        // update mutation stuff here
      })
      // write invalidate stuff here
    })
```